# Determine if exists a sub-space of V such as A's orthogonal projection on it is of norm x

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection

Let $V=M^{R}_{4X4}$ and A a matrix in V. How can I determine weather exists a sub-space of V such as A's orthogonal projection on it has a norm of x?

for example, if $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&-1 \\ -1&1&-1&1 \\ 1&-1&1&-1 \\ -1&1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and x=5.

I tried to use the fact that A's norm is 4, and therefore it's projection's norm can't be larger. On a second thought that is obviously incorrect, just like $(1,0)$'s projection on $Sp\{(1,1)\}$ is $(1,1)$ which has a larger norm than $(1,0)$.
So I'm stuck, and would love tips on how to approach this (in the specific case or in the general case).

*Edit- the orthogonal projection of $(1,0)$ on $Sp\{(1,1)\}$ is not $(1,1)$, it is $(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$, which has a norm of 1 (Thanks Michael Lee). So again I think that the norm of the orthogonal projection is always smaller than the norm of the original vector, but I don't know if it is true and if it is, how to prove it.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The orthogonal projection of $(1, 0)$ onto $\operatorname{Sp}\{(1, 1)\}$ is $(1/2, 1/2)$, not $(1, 1)$.

Comment: @MichaelLee you are right, that was stupid of me. So am I correct then that the orthogonal projection of a vector must have a norm smaller than it's own norm?

Comment: Yes, but can you reason out why this is true? Keep in mind the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$\lvert\langle u, v\rangle\rvert\leq \|u\|\|v\|$$

Comment: And, you made a mistake in your correction! The orthogonal projection is $(1/2, 1/2)$ (which has a norm of $1/\sqrt{2}$), not $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$. No square root. To see this, note that $(1/2, 1/2)-(1, 0) = (-1/2, 1/2)$, which is orthogonal to $(1, 1)$.